# How can I get index property in an itemController

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This case:

`{{#each array itemController="testController"}}`

I want to use index property in `itemController`:

```
App.TestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   // Is there any way to get index in this controller
})
```

or can I send a property with `#each` like this:

`{{#each array itemController="testController" property=index}}`

Thanks

======================================================================

UPDATE:

I do use a stupid way to solve this problem

```
var _temp_index = 0;
App.TestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    myIndex: null,
    init: function(){
        this._super();
        this.set('myIndex', _temp_index);
        _temp_index++;
    }
})
```

Look forward to a better solution!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that the itemViewClass on each keeps a reference to its contentIndex. You can do something like this in your handlebars:

```
<ul>
  {{#each item in model itemController="test" itemViewClass="App.ItemView"}}
     <li>{{item.content}} {{controller.index}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

And then just create an itemView that sets the controller index property:

```
App.ItemView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.get('controller').set('index',this.get('contentIndex'));
  }
});
```

Here is a fiddle of it working.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/EcUCiqO/2/edit

Comment: yeah,this is one way.But can not get the property directly Well by controller? I do not want to create several views. Thank you!

Comment: Lancezh, you only need to create one view, you could call it IndexedItemView or something. Every time you need to do this, just use that view. Ember is making the views in the background anyway even if you don't, so it won't affect computation time.

I don't think one should be trying to do this in the controller anyway, as the controllers are supposed to have no knowledge of their views, the views have to tell the controller about themselves.The index (or where you are in the render list) is a very view specific property, the itemController is meant to deal with individual items.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a way you can do it without needing an `itemViewClass`.

In your `itemController`:

```
export default Em.ObjectController.extend({ // I'm using ES6 syntax but you don't have to

  index: function() {
    var arrangedContent = this.get('target.content');
    var item = this.get('content');

    return arrangedContent.indexOf(item) + 1;
  }.property('target.content.@each.score'), // Change score to whatever property things are sorted by in the parent controller

});
```

In your template:

```
{{#each arrangedContent}}
  Index: {{index}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

use needs property to get ArrayController

this.get('model') get currentModel

use indexOf() to get the index

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without moving logic to view this way

1. Add index property to each model in array inside route

   ```
   App.SomeParentRoute = Ember.Route.extend

       setupController: (controller, model) ->
           model = model.map (item, index) -> item.set 'index', index

           controller.set 'model', model
   ```
2. Use array controller to store all data that will use itemController

   ```
   App.SomeParentController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
       itemController: 'someChild'
   ```
3. Now you have `index` property inside every itemController `someChild`

   ```
   App.SomeChildController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
       init: -> console.log @get('index')
   ```